# método que recorra el mismo atributo de distintas instancia de una clase c++

Tags: c++, class

Muy buenas, estoy intentando hacer un método que recorra el vector de cada instancia de una clase, y extrayendo cada vector para luego compararlos con una frase que inserto yo.

***EL CODIGO ESTA MAL EN ALGUNAS PARTES, EXPLICADO EN COMENTARIOS !!!!!***

Es decir, creo tres instancias de clase , cada una con su frase, y posteriormente agrego yo una frase a través de un método, para que descomponga mi frase en palabras(metiendolas en un vector) y compare esas palabras con las ya insertadas(y guardadas en sus correspondientes vectores).

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

```
class Example{


private:

string frase;
vector<string> palabras;


public:


Example (string frase);
const vector <string> getpalabras();
const float Similar(string text);

};



Example::Example (string frase){

  frase=this->frase;

}

const vector<string> Example::getPalabras(){

  return palabras;

}

const float Example::Similar(string frase){

  //creo un bucle for para recorrer cada posicion del vector guardado 
  //y compararlo con la 
  frase pasada por parametro

  for (unsigned int i=0;i<palabras.size();i++){

      if (frase==palabras[i])
        return 1;

      }

  return 0;
}

vector <string> Example::extraer(){


  vector <string> v;
 

  //Quito las palabras y voy guardandolas una a una
  stringstream bb (frase);

  while (bb>>frase) {

    v.push_back(frase);


  }


  return v;


 }
```

Ahora en el main, omitiendo los includes,etc..

```
//Creo las instancias con una frase

Example a("Hola buenos dias");
Example b("Adios amigo");
Example c("Buenas noches");

//Llamo al metodo extraer, para crear el vector con cada palabra

a.palabras=a.extraer();
b.palabras=b.extraer();
c.palabras=c.extraer();

//Llamo a similar, para ver su similitud

 float z=a.similar("Hola que tal"); //quiero que este metodo ya me recorra otras instancias.
```

¿Se podria hacer que el método SIMILAR recorra todos los vectores de cada instancia creada? , sin tener que llamar al metodo por cada instancia.

Comment: Puedes hacer que el método similar pase a ser static de la clase, para que no requiera ser llamado desde una instancia y como parámetros, que reciba un vector de tipo de tu clase y la frase. En el vector deberías agregar todas las instancias ya creadas.

Comment: Por que similar retorna un float ?

Comment: `frase=this->frase;` No, no quieres eso. `this->frase = frase` podría ser correcto. `a.palabras=a.extraer();` Esta asignación debe estar dentro de `extraer` porque `palabras` es privado. Esta línea no debe compilar. `extraer` probablemente  debería llamarse en la constructador. También, ¡sangra tu código!

Comment: ¿Qué `similar` debería volver? ¿Puedes mostrar algunos ejemplos de entradas y salidas específicas?

Comment: Muchas gracias  DarkFrostnight y  n. 'pronouns' m . Exactamente necesitaria como bien dices un metodo static para hacer eso, y muchas gracias por corregirme el codigo. Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para este tipo de tareas es preferible usar las variables locales.

Como apaño rápido, podrías crear un vector de vectores y usar bucles:

```
std::vector<Example*> examples = { &a, &b, &c };

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> palabras;
for( Example * example : examples )
{
  palabras.push_back(example->extraer());
}

int i = 0;
for( std::vector<std::string>> const& item : palabras )
{
  std::cout << "a.similar(palabras[" << i++ << "]) = " << a.similar(item) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias eferion